# Firebase snapshot returns object instead of array to iterate over

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using Firebase and Angular 5, I am using the snapshot method to retrieve data without listening for changes. I want to keep each item's index/key as it is being used for a link to navigate to a page for the clicked item.

Here is the TS:

```
  features = [];
  notfeatures = [];
  constructor(private Svc: Service, private http: HttpClient){

    firebase.database().ref('/reviews').once('value').then((snapshot)=> {
      console.log("snapshot", (snapshot.val()));
    ..........
```

Logging `(snapshot.val())` gives me an object (that I can't iterate over) of:

```
-L6ZwjBbyi4jz21OEoST: {category: "Movies", contributor: "CF1", feature: "No", …}

randomkey1: {category: "Movies", contributor: "CF1", feature: "No", …}

randomkey2: {category: "Movies", contributor: "DS1", feature: "Yes", …}

randomkey3: {category: "TV", contributor: "KH1", feature: "No", …}
```

So, I used `forEach` to get all items one by one and push them to two different arrays if a condition is met.

```
      ..........
      snapshot.forEach(snapshot => {
          console.log(snapshot.key, snapshot.val());
          if (snapshot.val().feature == "Yes") {
            this.features.push(snapshot.val())
            console.log("feature", this.features)
          }
          if (snapshot.val().feature == "No") {
            this.notfeatures.push(snapshot.val())
            console.log("notfeature", this.notfeatures)
          }
      });
    })

  }
```

However, doing this means that I lose `snapshot.key`, which I need for navigation.
How can I keep each item's `snapshot.key` for navigation / data purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it's not true that you can't iterate over the object returned by `snapshot.val()`. You can certainly [iterate over the key/value pairs in a javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties) with `for (x in y)` syntax.

But if you want to iterate over the children in the snapshot while retaining the unique key, you could put that value into the child object:

```
const val = snapshot.val()
val.id = snapshot.key
this.features.push(val)
```

Now you have an object for the snapshot with a new property called `id` that contains the unique key.

Comment: How can I push `val.id` with the corresponding `val`?

Comment: What do you mean?  If you do what I suggest and add it as a property to val, it becomes part of the object that you push.  I changed the code in my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Ah, I see. I expected only `snapshot.val()` to be pushed as it is declared as `val` and `val` is being pushed.